# How to target multiple templates in liquid unless statement

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-template

{% unless template == "templatename1" and  "templatename2" %}

or
{% if template == "templatename1" , "templatename2" %}

I would like to target "templatename2" as well but In this code, only "templatename1" is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to repeat the condition after the `and`. And it's a `or` because template cannot be both 1 and 2.

```
{% unless template == "templatename1" or template == "templatename2" %}
{% if template == "templatename1" or template == "templatename2" %}
```